# Sliding in out layout animation on scroll android

Tags: android, android-animation

I am trying to do a TranslateAnimation but don't work properly the layout apear and disapear but didn't do any animation. How could I solve this?
The  java code is this:

```
    private void initComponents() {

    ImageView postIV = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.post_view_activity_image_iv);

    CropBottonTransformation cropBottomTransformation = new CropBottonTransformation();

    Picasso.with(context).load(bundle.getString(Constants.POST_IMAGE))
            .centerCrop().fit().placeholder(R.drawable.home_placeholder)
            .into(postIV);

    TextView postTitleTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.post_view_activity_title_tv);
    postTitleTV.setText(bundle.getString(Constants.POST_TITLE));

    ObservableScrollView scroll = (ObservableScrollView) findViewById(R.id.post_view_activity_scroll);
    scroll.setScrollViewListener(this);

    hidenOptionsLL = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.post_view_activity_slide_options);
    hidenOptionsHeight = hidenOptionsLL.getHeight();
    slideRL = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.post_view_activity_slide_rl);
}
```

...

```
@Override
public void onScrollChanged(ObservableScrollView scrollView, int x, int y,
        int oldx, int oldy) {

    if (y > oldy) {
        if (sliding == false) {

            // Animation animation =
            // AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,
            // R.anim.slide_in_out);
            Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0,
                    hidenOptionsHeight, 0);
            animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(1.0f));
            animation.setDuration(600);
            hidenOptionsLL.startAnimation(animation);
            animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                    sliding = true;

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    sliding = false;
                    hidenOptionsLL.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });

        }

    } else if (y < oldy) {
        if (sliding == false) {

            // Animation animation =
            // AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,
            // R.anim.slide_in_out);
            Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0,
                    hidenOptionsHeight);
            hidenOptionsLL.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(1.0f));
            animation.setDuration(600);
            hidenOptionsLL.startAnimation(animation);
            animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                    sliding = true;

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    sliding = false;
                }
            });

        }
    }

}
```

The layout is this:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/post_view_activity_slide_options"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_down_float" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_up_float" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_radio" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

I don't find any solution. I want that it works like the options that appear on the bottom of the google search app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when I ask for the height at first time the view isn't visible an the value of the height was 0:

I did this:

```
ImageButton minusLetterIB = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.post_view_activity_minus_leters_ib);

    hidenOptionsHeight = minusLetterIB.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();
```

and changed the animation to hide an show the layout:

```
@Override
public void onScrollChanged(ObservableScrollView scrollView, int x, int y,
        int oldx, int oldy) {
    if (oldy - y > 20) {
        if (sliding == false) {
            if (slideRL.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0,
                        -hidenOptionsHeight, 0);

                animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(1.0f));
                animation.setDuration(400);
                slideRL.startAnimation(animation);
                animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                        sliding = true;
                        slideRL.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        sliding = false;
                        if (firstTimeSlideUp) {
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                    (int) hidenOptionsHeight);
                            FrameLayout extraLL = new FrameLayout(context);

                            extraLL.setBackgroundColor(getResources()
                                    .getColor(android.R.color.white));
                            scrollLL.addView(extraLL, 0, params);
                            firstTimeSlideUp = false;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    } else if (oldy - y < -20) {
        if (sliding == false) {
            Log.d("hiding view", "y " + y + " oldy " + oldy);

            if (slideRL.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0,
                        -hidenOptionsHeight);
                animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(1.0f));
                animation.setDuration(400);

                slideRL.startAnimation(animation);
                animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                        sliding = true;

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        sliding = false;
                        slideRL.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Slideinleft.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0%p"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"/>

Slideinright.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="-100%p" android:toXDelta="0%p"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime" />

Slideoutleft.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="-100%p"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime" />

Slideoutright.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="100%p"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime" />


use when go one activity to other.

overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right,
                        R.anim.slide_out_right);
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this library might help you:
https://github.com/flavienlaurent/discrollview?utm_source=Android+Weekly&utm_campaign=2daec38d18-Android_Weekly_86&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_4eb677ad19-2daec38d18-337293613

But otherwise, you're going to want to set fillEnabled fillBefore and fillAfter to true